# Is $(\mathbb{Q},<)$ elementary equivalent to $(\mathbb{R},<)$?

Tags: model-theory

I'm looking at those models over the language $\{<\}$.
For the case of $L=\{+\}$ there's already an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898788/are-bbb-r-and-bbb-q-elementary-equivalent).

Comment: Given that in the main body of your question you asked about models over the language $\{<\}$, I assumed you're asking about elementary equivalence between $(\mathbb{Q}, <)$ and $(\mathbb{R}, <)$ and thus took the liberty to edit the title of the question to reflect that. My answer below is also based on this reading of your intentions. If this is not what you intended, feel free to revert the edit.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The theory of dense linear orders without endpoints is complete, and both $(\mathbb{Q}, <)$ and $(\mathbb{R}, <)$ are models of this theory.

Comment: In fact, this is even mentioned in the question you linked to.